# .iso vs .img files for DVD images?

Tags: imovie, dvd, iso, idvd

There seem to be multiple standards for image files representing the contents of a DVD.  For example, iDVD creates `.img` files if told to burn a file rather than a DVD directly.  However, Linux install disks (for example) that are too big to fit on one CD (over 740 Mb or so) usually come in the form of `.iso` files meant to be converted to a physical DVD using `dd`, Toast, Disk Utility, or a comparable program.  Disk Utility can also mount an `.iso` image on the desktop so that it looks like a drive, much as with `.dmg` files.  So, several related questions:

- What exactly differentiates a DVD-size `.iso` from a DVD `.img`?
- Is there a simple conversion path from `.img` to `.iso`?
- Is `.img` an Apple-specific file format?
- If `.img` is Apple-specific, should I be worried about archiving DVD images that I want to keep permanently as `.img`s (i.e., is it possible that future software won't be able to read them)?

The last question speaks to the specific issue that brought this question to mind--I have a number of DVDs of home movies, painstakingly produced with iMovie and iDVD, that I would like to archive both as actual burnt video DVDs (i.e. for a DVD player) and as image files from which I can burn more copies if necessary.  But is `.img` the best format to do this, or are those likely to become obsolete?  Would `.iso` be better?  I'm interested in the general question of `.iso` vs `.img` (vs any other relevant formats) too, as the title of the question indicates.

Comment: Nice question. On my Mac I can just replace `.iso` with `.img` and vise versa.

Answer (score 6):

**Single-track (`.iso`) vs. multiple-track (`.img`)**

> Any single-track CD-ROM, DVD or Blu-ray disc can be archived in ISO
>   format as a true digital copy of the original.
>
> But ISO files have limitations. For example, a CD can have multiple
>   tracks, which can contain computer data, audio, or video. File systems
>   such as ISO 9660 are stored inside one of these tracks. Since ISO
>   images are expected to contain a binary copy of the file system and
>   its contents, there is no concept of a "track" inside an ISO image,
>   since a track is a container for the contents of an ISO image. This
>   means that CDs with multiple tracks can't be stored inside a single
>   ISO image; at most, an ISO image will contain the data inside one of
>   those multiple tracks, and only if it is stored inside a standard file
>   system.
>
> Formats such as CUE/BIN, CCD/IMG and MDS/MDF formats can be used to
>   store multi-track disc images, including CD-Audio discs. These formats
>   store a raw disc image of the complete disc, including information
>   from all tracks, along with a companion file describing the multiple
>   tracks and the characteristics of each of those tracks. This would
>   allow an optical media burning tool to have all the information
>   required to correctly burn the image on a new disc.

*Shamelessly copied (an slightly edited) from [wiki/ISO_image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) (24-10-2015).*

Comment: Interesting.  Good find.  This seems to disagree with your comment above, though.  If an `.img` is a metaformat of sorts that can contain `.iso`s and "a companion file describing the multiple tracks..." then how can you just change the extension on an `.img` and make a valid `.iso` out of it?  I would think that the metadata would come across as noise.

Comment: Because I only encountered single track IMG files so far;)

Comment: Aha, ok, so perhaps all valid `.iso`s are valid `.img`s (just single-track `.img`s) but not vice versa.

Comment: That is correct