# macOS: How to read the file system of a disc image

Tags: terminal, filesystem, disk-image

is there terminal command that shows/reads the file system(s) (and versions) of a .iso or .dmg image?

E.g. Udf 2.50/Joliet/hfs+

Comment: Perhaps mount the image first and then use `diskutil info /dev/<disk#>`?

Comment: I’ve linked in my answer to some details like @JoyJin has helpfully commented. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/73931/5472 as asked this is basically a yes/no question.

Comment: Read the _manual pages_ for `hdiutil` and `diskutil`. You can read the _manual page_ for _`command`_ in **Terminal** by typing _`command`_ and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you can read the details from ISO and DMG from the command line using OS provided tools.

The primary command line tool to manipulate disk images is `hdiutil` and you may need to attach / authenticate / mount them and use `diskutil` to determine file systems contained within a [dmg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/73926/5472) or [iso](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/212570/5472) if the wrapper doesn't contain the information you require.

The option I use is `hdiutil imageinfo` but also `hdiutil fsinfo` has exceptional details on these containers that may be useful to you.

```
% hdiutil imageinfo foo.dmg
Format Description: UDIF read-only compressed (zlib)
Class Name: CUDIFDiskImage
Checksum Type: CRC32
Size Information:
        CUDIFEncoding-bytes-total: 1015091
        Total Empty Bytes: 13726208
        Sector Count: 30730
        Total Bytes: 15733760
        CUDIFEncoding-bytes-wasted: 0
        Total Non-Empty Bytes: 2007552
        Compressed Ratio: 0.50548329507778633
        CUDIFEncoding-bytes-in-use: 1015091
        Compressed Bytes: 1015091
Checksum Value: $81F7C3A0
Segments:
        0: /Users/me/foo.dmg
Partition Information:
        1:
                Name: disk image (Apple_HFS : 2)
                Partition Number: 1
                Checksum Type: CRC32
                Checksum Value: $AAEEB101
        -1:
                Name: Driver Descriptor Map (DDM : 0)
                Partition Number: -1
                Checksum Type: CRC32
                Checksum Value: $77150592
        2:
                Name:  (Apple_Free : 3)
                Partition Number: 2
                Checksum Type: CRC32
                Checksum Value: $00000000
        0:
                Name: Apple (Apple_partition_map : 1)
                Partition Number: 0
                Checksum Type: CRC32
                Checksum Value: $5AC9B785
Format: UDZO
```

There are dozens of verbs to send to the tool, so I suppose the one you need may vary based on your specific query against the data contained within the packaged file.

Comment: But hdiutil does not show me the file systems of an existing image.

Comment: ISO and DMG are packages. Their version is shown in info. @user400439 perhaps the [tour] will help you refine your question by showing some research? There may be several questions here TBH.

Comment: Does `hdiutil fsid` get the enclosed filesystsm? I can't test as I don't have anything that's not HFS+

Comment: @Tetsujin, Yes, `hdiutil fsid` works on the **ISO** _images_ I tested it on. Which reported the expected **ISO 9660** _filesystem_ as well as **UDF**, and on a hybrid _disc_ it even reported a **FAT12** partition, among  others on that _disc_.

Comment: `hdiutil imageinfo` is the one I use the most, but OP here is so vague, we can't really guess what level of knowledge they have, what they're doing or what research / actual problem they face is... (do they know what a `man` page is? do they really just need to know which ISO are PC and need a one liner with `awk|sed|grep` treatment, etc...

Comment: ok, I tested the commands and they are really useful, thank you all! But I was not able to read the version of the file system. E.g. is the UDF file system version 1.50 or 2.60, etc. Is there a command to read get the version? The man pages do not show any hints regarding udf versions

Comment: You might have to upload a sample file. The commands work for all the images I have @user400439 how did you come across your files?

Comment: Use `hdiutil create -size 1m -fs UDF -volname Test ~/Desktop/Test.dmg` followed by `newfs_udf --wipefs yes -b 2048 -r 2.60 -v Test ~/Desktop/Test.dmg` Now I need a terminal command which shows me: "UDF 2.60". The commands show me that the fs is UDF but not the version (2.60). Or did I miss something?